# Fantasy-type book where a girl’s dad is beheaded by logs, she has a blind friend with synesthesia, and she meets her soulmate in a dream world

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this fantasy-type book around 2010–2012, and I only remember a few things about it.

1. The main character's dad is dead because he was riding a motorcycle or something and was beheaded by logs from a semitruck or something like that.
2. The girl has a friend who is blind but has synesthesia.
3. It was a series, and in one of the books, she has sex with a guy in a pond in, like, a dream world, and all the frogs and fish boil or something.
4. That's like the whole thing with the series: she and this guy meet in this dream world, but then she meets him in real life.

I think I read it around 2010–2012, and I think I remember there being actual magic too, like maybe there was a magical quest or curse. I think the girl ended up living with her grandma, who sort of introduced the magic world to the girl and said the dad died because of evil people, not just a freak accident.

It took place in New Mexico or Arizona too, and the guy in her dreams is like her soul mate or something, but I want to say that they meet in real life and hate each other.

This book was like a fever dream for me, and maybe I am mixing up a couple of different books I read around that time, but please give me any titles you think it might be.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  We don't know how old you are, so we don't know when you were 12.  Approximately what _year_ did you read this?  Also, are there any actual science fiction or fantasy aspects to the story, or is it just dreams?

Comment: I think I read it around 2010-2012, and I think I remember there being like actual magic too, like maybe there was a magical quest or curse. I think the girl ended up living with her grandma who sort of introduced the magic world to the girl and said the dad died because of evil people not just a freak accident

Comment: it took place in New Mexico or Arizona too and the guy in her dreams is like her soul mate or something but I want to say that they meet in real life and hate each other

Comment: *Running with the Demon* hits some of these beats but not all

Comment: I updated the title- and I don’t think it’s Running with the Demon I looked it up and it’s not familiar at all.